# Rewriting a variable in a querystring with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use a PHP script with my site that produces a querystring in the URL. One of the variables in the querystring is: `colour=red`

I would like to make a rule in my .htaccess file that re-writes all instances of `colour=red` to `colour=blue`.

I don't have access to change the original PHP script so a .htaccess rule is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)colour=red(&.*|)$  # search colour=red
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1colour=blue%2 [L,R=301]       # redirect to colour=blue
```

This will redirect URLs with `colour=red` in query-string to URLs with `colour=blue`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It didn't work, got an 'Internal Server Error' when I added your code to my .htaccess I'm afraid.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` available/enabled? In my case it worked as expected.

Comment: Hi, yes mod_rewrite is enabled on my server. I use it frequently to redirect certain pages and also to re-write. When adding your code to .htaccess an 'Internal Server Error' is encountered. Just in case, I commented out all other rules within my .htaccess file, but no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: The code above kind of only half solves my problem. Does anybody know how to actually re-direct the URL so that the querystring actually includes `colour=blue` rather than just `$_GET` ing it?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it will actually replace `colour=red` with `colour=blue` and redirect to it.